# Can we get the following flexibility in Python as In Perl

Tags: python, perl

Sorry. I am not trying to start any flame. My scripting experience is from Perl, and I am pretty new in Python.

I just want to check whether I can have the same degree of flexibility as in Python.

In Python :

```
page = form.getvalue("page")
str = 'This is string : ' + str(int(page) + 1)
```

In Perl :

```
$str = 'This is string : ' . ($page + 1);
```

Is there any way I can avoid int / str conversion?

Comment: Seems like you need something between your "module that reads the form" and "module that prints the output" that actually understands the incoming data, and stores it as the proper type.  After you've validated "page", for example, it should become an integer.  Then the rest of your code doesn't need to worry about coercing -- it's already the right type.  (I would do this in Perl, too, FWIW.)

Comment: The Perl version would be:  
    $str = 'This is string : ' . ($page + 1);

Comment: If you want to write perish code, use Perl. Otherwise, you're welcome to learn the pythonic ways and write proper Python code. Once you go down that route, you won't miss Perl much anyway.

Comment: @Sean:  Indeed.  Edited to correct Perl string concatenation operator.

Comment: If you do not want to start a flame war, simply phrase the question as a Python question. As far as I can see, there is absolutely no reason to mention Perl at all in this question except that you seem to want to make an unfavorable comparison to Python (flexibility is generally regarded as a good thing although Perl occasionally feels compelled to prove that too much cake can make you sick).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, since Python is strongly typed. If you keep `page` as an int you can do the following:

```
s = 'This is string : %d' % (page + 1,)
```

Comment: Then again, it will coerce for you; there's no problem using %s instead of %r above.

Comment: @Nicholas: Sure, but if you use `%s` instead then you lose the capabilities that `%d` has when doing string formatting.

Comment: It's nothing to do with strong typing really, just that the operation for adding a `str` and an `int` together is not defined. This is a deliberate choice, should the result of `'1'+2` be '12', '3', or 3?

Comment: Please someone explain to me how python is a strongly type language? i have always thought otherwise

Comment: @gath: You're confusing strongly/weakly typed with statically/dynamically typed. Python is strongly, dynamically typed.

Comment: You do not need a tuple: `(page+1)` is sufficient.

Comment: @gath, Hard to answer in the comments - maybe you should open a question for it

Comment: Shouldn't it be `s = 'This is string : %d' % (int(page) + 1,)`? 'page` appears to be a string and needs to be explicitly converted into an `int`.

Comment: @gath: Open a new question on that topic.  Better yet, look at all of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+strongly+typed

Comment: @MAK: See the second sentence.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `page` is a `str`

```
page = form.getvalue("page")
S = 'This is string : %d'%(int(page)+1)
```

otherwise make page an `int`

```
page = int(form.getvalue("page"))
S = 'This is string : %d'%(page+1)
```

For the record (and to show that this is nothing to do with strong typing), you can also do crazy stuff like this:

```
>>> class strplus(int):
...  def __radd__(self, other):
...   return str(int(other).__add__(self))
... 
>>> page = form.getvalue("page")
>>> page + strplus(1)
'3'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
mystr = "This string is: %s" % (int(page) + 1)
```

... the string conversion will be automatic when interpolating into the `%s` via the `%` (string formating operator).

You can't get around the need to convert from string to integer.  Python will never conflate strings for other data types.  In various contexts Python can return the string or "representation" of an object so there are some implicit data casts into string forms.  (Under the hood these call `.__str__()` or `.__repr__()` object methods).

(While some folks don't like it I personally think the notion of overloading `%` for string interpolation is far more sensible than a function named `sprintf()` (if you have a language with operator overloading support anyway).

Answer (score 0):

No. Python doesn't have the same level of polymorphism as perl. You can print anything, and mix and match floats and ints quite easily, and lots of things (0, '', "", () and []) all end up False, but no, it's not perl in terms of polymorphism.

Comment: The issue is strongly typed versus weakly typed, not polymorphism.

Comment: You could imagine that Perl values are functions of zero arguments with polymorphic return types.  (But they're not.)

Comment: @jrockway: Scalar::Util::dualvar